# How to deconstruct a parameter in an arrow notation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a function in React

```
function Header = ({ props }) => <div className={props.classes.container}/>
```

My current eslint config rightfully prevents me from having this code because the props object has to be deconstructed

I can achieve the desired result by using

```
const Header = function Header(props) {
 const { classes } = props
 return <div className={classes.container}/>
}
```

This solves my problem, but I'd rather have everything in an arrow notation. Is it possible to achieve a result similar to my second example with an arrow notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional component (a function or an arrow functions) gets props as it's first parameter, so you can deconstruct classes directly:

```
const Header = ({ classes }) => <div className={classes.container}/>
```

It's the same thing with a standard JS function:

```
function Header({ classes }) {
    return <div className={classes.container}/>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but the line will be longer. Your linter might want you to split the line it's too long:

```
const Header = ({ props: { classes: { container } } }) => <div className={container}/>
```